# AD B2C Login support in Zebra Enterprise browser 1.7

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, windows-embedded-compact

I am planning to create a web app in .net to run in MK3100 enterprise browser. The requirement is that the login for the web app is to be provided through Azure AD B2C. I would like to know if the AD B2C login page would work in the enterprise browser. If not do we have any other alternatives to support AD B2C in enterprise browser.

Answer (score 0):

You would be unlikely to find somebody who could answer that question without access to hardware but, if possible, I suggest just trying it with the unlicensed version of Enterprise Browser 1.7 since the unlicensed version of the product is fully featured, it just presents a nag screen.